# How to send parameters in $ .get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to send two parameters in $ .get to the onget page, but these two parameters will be sent blank. Did I pass wrong in $ .get?
My question is, did I pass these parameters correctly in $ .get?

```
 function DeleteEpisode(episodeid) {
  var corseid = document.getElementById("corseidfordelete").value;
Swal.fire({
title: 'delet؟',
showDenyButton: true,
confirmButtonText: 'yes',
denyButtonText: `no`,
}).then((result) => {
if (result.isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire('save!', '', 'success').then((r) => {
        if (r.isConfirmed)
        {   
            $.get("/Admin/Courses/IndexEpisode/? 
         id="+corseid+"episodeid="+episodeid);                              
        }
    })                           
} else if (result.isDenied) {
    Swal.fire('error', '', 'info')
}
}) };
```

Method onget

```
   public void OnGet(long id,long episodeid=0 )
    { 
      _CourseEpisodeApplication.DeleteEpisode(episodeid);
      courseid=id;
      lstEpisode=_CourseEpisodeApplication.GetCourseEpisode(id);                                                       
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors.

 First one is that you did not specify the query separator `&` in your URI

Here is the fixed one.

```js
$.get("/Admin/Courses/IndexEpisode/?id="+corseid+"&episodeid="+episodeid);
```

Secondly, based on your code. The browser will throw an error due to unescaped break line.

```js
$.get("/Admin/Courses/IndexEpisode/?  <---
       -->  id="+corseid+"episodeid="+episodeid);
```

For future reference, just use jQuery PlainObject

```js
 $.get('/Admin/Courses/IndexEpisode/', {
        id: corseid,
        episodeid: episodeid
    });
```